# Script run in subshell not running same shell as calling script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have shell A that calls shell B using nohup.

SHELL A:

```
echo "\r\n OS1 : $BASH \r\n"
echo "\r\n OS2 : $SHELL \r\n"

$scriptB="B.sh"

(
  nohup sh $scriptB $* >> test.log 2>&1
  echo process finalized
  exit
)
```

SHELL B:

```
echo "\r\n OS1 : $BASH \r\n"
echo "\r\n OS2 : $SHELL \r\n"
```

In shell A I get the echo result:

```
OS1 : /usr/bin/bash
OS2 : /usr/bin/sh
```

In shell B I get the echo result:

```
OS1 : 
OS2 : /usr/bin/sh
```

Why is the bash emptied in the call? How can I keep using bash in the subscript?

This is causing me syntax errors in some commands that are available in bash but not is sh

Comment: [shebang?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

Comment: `$scriptB=B.sh
(nohup sh $scriptB $* >> test.log 2>&1
 echo process finalized
exit)` Can you modify the formatting a bit? It is quite not clear

Comment: `$scriptB=B.sh` is an erroneous syntax

Comment: @lnian this is the shell file name, I bet it needs quotes, but this is not the main problem here

Comment: @FredrikPihl can you please elaborate how shebang helps here?

Comment: @KAD I could be wrong but this might be fixed by using 'source' instead of 'sh' to call your second script. Could you try `source /full/path/to/B.sh` instead of just calling `sh B.sh` ?

Comment: BASH environment variable is not mandatory; probably it is set up by some rc file. However you can export it from the first script (export BASH). If you instead want the second script to be executed by bash and not /bin/sh (which could point to something else), call it directly: nohup /bin/bash ...

Comment: sometimes `/bin/sh -> bash*` sometimes not. `echo $0` gives shell

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

File **A.sh**

```
echo "\r\n OS1 : $BASH \r\n"
echo "\r\n OS2 : $SHELL \r\n"

(
  nohup sh ./B.sh $* >> test.log 2>&1
  echo process finalized
  exit
)
```

and keep the File B as it is, it printed out the same output for both.